# Javascript regex problems around \n

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a text pattern that I am trying to replace in a node.js application. The pattern is:

```
***
some text
***
```

It is created in javascript with the following code:

```
var textblock = "***" + '\n' + 'some text' + '\n' + "***" + 'the rest of the text block'
```

The following regular expression works in regexpal and seems correct to me:

```
\*{3}\n.+\n\*{3}
```

But when I put it in my javascript code, it fails:

```
textblock.match(/\*{3}\n.+\n\*{3}/)   // returns null
```

I tested, and even just *{3}\n doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something idiosyncratic about how javascript handles \n ? I've tried /m as well, and I've also tried [\n\r].

Thanks!

UPDATE: turns out that the GitHub API markdown processes issue body text and eliminates newlines. So my regex *was* correct, but I was wrong about the text I was matching in.

Comment: works fine for me !!! Check textblock var...

Comment: Worsk for me. What is textblock variable - i guess problem is there...

Comment: `"***\nsome text\n***".match(/\*{3}\n.+\n\*{3}/)` works for me, does your actual string data perhaps use `\r\n`, not `\n`?

Comment: You said that `/*{3}\n/` doesn't work, but you missed the `\`; it should be `/\*{3}\n/`.

Comment: Sorry, the textblock variable inconsistency was intentional but confusing (t was the prepended text I'm trying to match, textblock was the entire string in which the text appeared). I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, I just tried [/r/n], no difference.

Comment: @DavidKnipe, I do have a backspace, but the SO markdown omitted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `textblock` to `t`:

```
var t = "***" + '\n' + 'some text' + '\n' + "***";
alert(t.match(/\*{1}\n.+\n\*{1}/));
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DATwb/); removed some * from the regexp to check if it is working properly).

Comment: Sorry, that was intentional. t was meant to be just the text I'm trying to match, within a larger text block called textblock.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with line-endings. If you match for `[\n\r]` instead of just `\n` it works OK.

Here is a fiddle  to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/xD8a5/

Answer (score 0):

The text I'm finding and replacing comes from a GitHub issue fetched via API. Turns out that when you put multiple asterisks in a row, they omit the newline chars before and after since they convert it into a graphical line.

The answer was to not require actual newline characters. This worked:

```
match(/\*{3}[\n\r]*.+[\n\r]*\*{3}/)
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\n` instead of `\n` i tried on my code and it is working fine